# -XX:+TraceClassLoading equivalent for JRockit

Tags: debugging, jvm, classloader, jrockit

We are having classloading issues and we want to trace the JVM classloader. On Sun JVM we generally use the -XX:+TraceClassLoading flags to throw some light at the problem, but this time we are using JRockit.

Do any of you know if there is a way to get the same class loading information from the JRockit JVM?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [this page](http://www.javamonamour.org/2009/11/beauty-of-verboseclass.html) I've found that JRockit supports the more standard  `-verbose:class` way of showing class loader traces.